# How do I run Viber as root on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: root, gui, chromium, qt, viber

I installed Viber on Ubuntu 19.04 in `/opt/viber`.
I start it, nothing happens.
I open a terminal at `/opt/viber/Viber`:

```
root@asshat:/opt/viber# ./Viber
[16075:16075:0430/092527.937550:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)]
Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported.
See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

Then I try `/opt/viber/Viber --no-sandbox` but I continue to get this error message.
Now a `grep -ir "Running as root"` yields

```
Binary file ./lib/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5 matches
```

Is there a way to configure `--no-sandbox` in libQt5WebEngineCore?
I need to run it when logged-in as root...

Or any other way to run viber as another user when logged in as root, without compromising `xhost acces -`.

OK, so I'm gonna run it as non root user.
So I do:

```
su nonrootuser
sudo xhost local:root
./Viber
```

Now it starts, but it says "no internet connection".
How can I fix that?

Never mind, it doesn't work as normal user anyway, because the SSL version of viber is incompatible with the SSL-version of Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: That's not how Debian/Ubuntu should work.

Comment: "I need to run it when logged-in as root..." No and it is best to drop this kind of behaviour. You are creating a big whooping security hole into your system. The correct way to start viber is `$ /opt/viber/Viber`. Software in /opt/ is installed as is from a 3rd party installer and the ONLY connection to your system should be a service (upstart or systemd for newer Ubuntu). There is never need to use software in /opt/ with root. We take security serious ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind: The very fact that you can run software that has access to everything the user has read (or write) permission to is a security hole. It doesn't much matter if you run it as root or not, if there's just one user on the system. I don't see how one can call this "taking security seriously". If I'm an evil employee at viber (or an FSB-employee), I can encrypt all your data, including emails, and/or sell it to god-knows-who. Actually, you're safer running as root, because then an attacker has no idea where your data is, because as root, you can put it anywhere, not just in your home.

Comment: @Rinzwind: If you take security seriously, that means you run ChromeOS (own build) and save your data to your own cloud, and process it with your own web-applications (without the dubious help of npm). I own one with ARM-processor, just to be on the safe side. The ubuntu motto seems to be: either you trust viber, or you don't. I don't see how you can call this "security" in the first place. So why not just run it as root. Any sensitive data on the hd is already encrypted anyway (PGP).

Comment: You can use the [Viber snap app](https://snapcraft.io/viber-unofficial) to prevent that.

Comment: *"Actually, you're safer running as root, because then an attacker has no idea where your data is"*. This makes automatic attacks a bit more complex, but nothing is safer. Anyways, as a normal user you can put the data anywhere you want, too. Make your photo and documents archive read-only or have it in a container and mount it (sudo-only) only when needed etc. etc. There's a lot you can do security-wise using normal user, but much less if an attacker has root.

Comment: @RoVo: No, you cannot put your files where you want, because you don't have the rights. But I agree that this doesn't make you safe. Thanks for the snap tip, didn't know snap could run gui apps. But appart from being on the slow side of requiring vast hd-space (already 93% full), it doesn't work when run as root...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here it comes. 
From https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-platform-notes.html

> To explicitly disable sandboxing, the QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX 
>   environment variable can be set to 1 or alternatively the --no-sandbox
>   command line argument can be passed to the user application
>   executable (passing argument to viber has no effect).

So this does the trick:

```
export QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX=1
/opt/viber/Viber
```

However, both snapcraft and flatpack don't have extensive enough debugging capabilitites to do this in a reasonable amount of time.

But it's possible to create a [**working** docker-image](https://github.com/ststeiger/viber-root-docker) in a significantly shorter amount of time than the excessive time it takes to create a, for unknown reasons, not-working snapcraft-package: